# JQuery Drop big Object with pointer tolerance

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, droppable

I'm stuck with the following:

```
 $(this).draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    containment: "#parent",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
});

 $(this).droppable({
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    drop: M_DropObject,
    hoverClass: "ActiveDropZone"
});
```

where I am trying to drag and drop big objects into small drop zone;

Drop action does not always succeed (most likely when clicking the draggable object in the middle).The droppable tolerance is set to 'pointer', but the drop zone does not respond even when pointer is hovering it.
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mRizk/vb7veopu/9/).

Comment: Please read [MCVE]. You need to provide the minimal code actually producint the bugg in the question itself (not just on JSFiddle), as well as details about what the actual behavior and the desired behavior is.

Comment: Question Updated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the `containment` option is causing this problem.
I removed it and drop works correctly.

```
$(this).draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    //containment: "#parent",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: 'invalid'
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mRizk/vb7veopu/10/).